# Failed to connect to Websocket on iPhone

Tags: ios, nginx, react-native, websocket, django-channels

I am working on my project and it runs **perfectly fine on my IOS simulator** (from emulator, I can access to my server hosted on `Google Instance VM`, `websocket` worked just fine). However, when I run it on the real device, it cannot connect to my server (`Django` with `channels` and `redis`, `Nginx`) to get the data

When I checked on the xcode log, I saw a lot of error like this

```
2018-04-12 19:30:28.137787+1000 mobile[3481:2168168] TCP Conn 0x1c0365e80 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2018-04-12 19:30:28.198073+1000 mobile[3481:2168168] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 310 Connection has no connected handler
2018-04-12 19:30:28.198184+1000 mobile[3481:2168168] TCP Conn 0x1c4172c00 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2018-04-12 19:30:28.323076+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 311 Connection has no connected handler
2018-04-12 19:30:28.323190+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] TCP Conn 0x1c0367680 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2018-04-12 19:30:28.452909+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 312 Connection has no connected handler
2018-04-12 19:30:28.453017+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] TCP Conn 0x1c03675c0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2018-04-12 19:30:28.589833+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 313 Connection has no connected handler
2018-04-12 19:30:28.589946+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] TCP Conn 0x1c03675c0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2018-04-12 19:30:28.643707+1000 mobile[3481:2168168] [] nw_socket_connect connectx failed (fd 16, 127.0.0.1:8097 stream, pid: 3481) [61: Connection refused]
2018-04-12 19:30:28.647380+1000 mobile[3481:2167866] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 314 Connection has no connected handler
```

My websocket code on the mobile is quite simple and it used the standard `websocket` from React Native (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

```
    socket.onopen = () => {

        };

        socket.onmessage = (e) => {

        };

        socket.onerror = (e) => {
          console.log(e.message);
        };

        socket.onclose = (e) => {
          console.log(e.code, e.reason);
        };
```

My Nginx configuration is like this

```
server {
listen 80;
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
 }
}
```

Is there anyone having the same issue ? It is really disappointed that I used the native WebSocket from React Native and it does not work like expected, but before that, in the previous version of my app, I used "socket.io" and it worked just fine. I am using `react native 0.50`

Comment: Are you trying to connect to 127.0.0.1?  On your phone, that will be your phone. You need to connect to the IP address of your server.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank for your input. My mobile connect to `nginx` on the server (`google vm`), then `nginx` re-route the request to the `django` server running on local `(127.0.0.1)`

Comment: Have you enabled [ATS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#1-enable-app-transport-security) for your server domain?

Comment: @Stackia awesome. you just remind me this step. I actually did it in my old version but miss this one on the new version. I will do it after I wake up. Thank a lot man, i will update you if it overcome the issue

Comment: @Stackia sorry, it does not work. I am not sure how come this stuck in my mind that this is the solution :(

Comment: Sorry guys, i figured the broken code that made it does not work and it does not relate to the network settings. Thanks all. Will delete this question soon